# Change background color of a cell based on value from previous details value

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I have a custom report that shows some numbers in the form of a simple table report. The problem is changing the background color of a cell based on previous data. Consider this image:

[image]

I want to change the background color of the cell with value 156 into red because in the previous record in the third column I have a value lower than 100.

How I can do this with SQL Server reporting service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the [Previous function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156372%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx) that allows you to access the field values of the previous row. So in the cell for the second column you could write an expression like the following for the BackgroundColor property:

```
=IIF(Fields!SecondColumn.Value > Previous(Fields!ThirdColumn.Value), "Red", "Transparent")
```